# Strongly typed enums for python (mypy)

Tags: python, enums, mypy

I am using `mypy` for typing but it doesn't work well for `Enum`

Most of the enums I define are only integer mappings

For eg.

```
class Role(Enum):
    ENG = 0
    PRODUCT = 1
    BUSINESS = 2
    FOUNDER = 3
```

When I make an enum and try to get its value (to store it in the `db`), its type is inferred as Any.

```
a = Role(2)
a.value  # inferred as Any instead of int
```

How can I change this to get better typing? I don't mind making a new base class and using it instead of Enum.

Comment: Can you use IntEnum for this!